# Echoing large string in PHP results in no output at all

Tags: php, echo

I am helping to build a Joomla site (using Joomla 1.5.26). One of the pages are really really big. As a result, PHP just stops working without any error and all previously printed strings are ignored. There is no output at all. We have display_errors set to TRUE and error_reporting set to E_ALL.

I found the exact line where PHP breaks. It's in libraries/joomla/application/component/view.php:196

```
function display($tpl = null)
{
    $result = $this->loadTemplate($tpl);
    if (JError::isError($result)) {
        return $result;
    }

    echo $result;
}
```

Some information:

- Replacing echo $result; with echo strlen($result); works. The length of the string is 257759.
- echo substr($result, 0, 103396); is printing partial content.
- echo substr($result, 0, 103397); results in no output at all.
- echo substr($result, 0, 103396) . "A"; results in no output at all. So splitting string into chunks is not a solution.

I have checked server performance during the execution of the script. CPU usage is 100% but there's plenty of memory left. PHP memory limit is 1024M. output_buffering is 4096 but I tried setting it to unreasonably high number - dies at exact same position. Server runs Apache 2.2.14-5ubuntu8.10 and PHP 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.18. PHP runs as fast_cgi module.

I have never experienced something like that and Google search results in nothing also. Have any of you experienced something like that and know the solution?
Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try exploding the string and looping through each line.

You could also try this, found on [php.net - echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php):

```
<?php
function echobig($string, $bufferSize = 8192)
{
   // suggest doing a test for Integer & positive bufferSize
   for ($chars = strlen($string)-1, $start = 0;$start <= $chars; $start += $bufferSize) {
       echo substr($string, $start, $bufferSize);
   }
}
?>
```

Basically, it seems echo can't handle such large data in one call. Breaking it up somehow should get you where you need to go.

Comment: Well, I mentioned that echo substr($result, 0, 103396) . "A"; results in no output at all. So splitting string into chunks is not a solution. This is not working. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: I can't believe that this fixes my out of memory error... PHP is really the only language where you have to write such stupid helper functions to simply echo a string.

Answer (score 0):

what about try using `print_r` rather than `echo`

```
function display($tpl = null)
{
    $result = $this->loadTemplate($tpl);
    if (JError::isError($result)) {
        return $result;
    }

    print_r($result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this on the CLI and it works fine with PHP 5.4.11 and 5.3.15:

```
$str = '';                                                                           
for ($i=0;$i<257759;$i++) {                                                          
    $str .= 'a';                                                                     
}                                                                                    
echo $str;
```

It seems a reasonable assumption that PHP itself works fine, but that the output buffer is too large for Apache/fast_cgi. I would investigate the Apache config further. Do you have any special Apache settings?

Comment: You are right - it works on CLI but doesn't with Apache. Thanks for pointing this, I will investigate further. We're using default Apache settings that came with Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: I was wrong - it seems that Apache is also working with this script. What's interesting - if I replace echo $result with your script, it also works. Something must be wrong with the $result then.

Answer (score 0):

May be [that](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=18029)?

Try something like this

```
php_flag output_buffering On
```

Or try to turn on gzip in Joomla!

Or use nginx as reverse proxy or standalone server :^ )

Answer (score 0):

It seems I solved the problem by myself. It was somewhat unexpected thing - faulty HTML formatting. We use a template for order page and inside there is a loop which shows all ordered products. When there were a few products, everything worked great but when I tried to do the same with 40 products, the page did break.
However I still don't understand why the server response would be empty with status code 200.

Thanks for answers, everybody!